# Look for preg_match() for all files of a directory (recursively)

Tags: php

I would like to know how can I (recursively) scan a directory files (100+) looking for a `preg_match()` in files contents. I'm looking if any file contains a backtick (`).

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: You can put `glob` in recursive method by checking `is_dir`. then use the `preg_match`.

Comment: Will it work for subfolders as well? I need to check only FILES and only ITS CONTENTS, not file names. May you answer with a working code? Thanks.

Comment: I have added a basic version of it, I'm not sure about the memory usage or timeout errors based on your file sizes and counts.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it, using **php** function [`opendir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php) try this function :

```
    <?php
    function findbacktick ($dir){
    // Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                preg_match("/'/", $file, $matches);
                if (count($matches)>=1) {
                    echo 'file contains a backtick : '.$file.'</br>-----</br>';
                }
            }
            closedir($dh);
        }
    }
    }
    $dir = "path/to/dir";
    findbacktick ($dir);
    ?>
```

Comment: This will look for file contents of every subfolders files as well of a directory? I'm looking for backticks for security, is there anyway i can check if a file contents contains an array of preg matchs like if it contains the shell() function, shell_exec(), etc..?

Comment: ohhh ok. I get it.

Comment: For now it is getting, all file in DIR folder

Comment: I need subfolders files too

Comment: Hello, i hope not to bother you, i'm waiting

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap `glob` in recursive function. I'm giving you the idea with following basic version of it.

```
function find_files($dir, $files = []) {
    foreach (glob($dir."/*") as $file) {
        if(is_dir($file)) {
            $files = find_files($file, $files);
        }
        $content = file_get_contents($dir."/".$file);
        if(preg_match('/[YOUR_PATTERN]/', $content)) {
            $files[] = $file;
        }

    }
    return $files;
}
```

I haven't tried it, but I guess it should work.

PS. It might give you the memory exhausted error or timeout error.

Comment: Thanks ! What is `$files` in the function parameter?

Comment: That's an optional empty array to keep track of your files, as it is a recursive function. You don't need to pass it. Please read `optional arguments in php functions`.

Comment: Ok, but one question more. Can you add array of preg match support? I want it to check if preg match of exec and ` (backtics)

Comment: Nvm my last comment, there's an issue. Error (php application) `ErrorException: "file_get_contents(/home/eternalfactions/server/plugins/AlwaysSpawn//home/eternalfactions/server/plugins/AlwaysSpawn/plugin.yml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory" (EXCEPTION) in "main/src/main/Main" at line 58` – It says no such file or directory, it is not properly doing the recursive thing, as you see it is cloning the path